# Using Malcom API to send push notifications to specific user

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, malcom

I'm using [Malcom](http://mymalcom.com/) API to send push notifications to my users.
I'm using `+ (void)identifyUserWithName:(NSString *) name mail:(NSString *) mail;` in my iOS client but I need to know how to send push notifications to specific users using his name or email.
I haven't found anything in the [documentation](https://github.com/MyMalcom/MalcomAPI).
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Malcom only saves that information so far. There's no way to send push notifications given an email.

Anyway you could send pushes straight to an unique device thanks to Malcom Identifier. Look into [Malcom API documentation](https://github.com/MyMalcom/MalcomAPI) to see `UDIDS` field in the body of a push request.